# how to remove old video frame delay render webrtc android?

Tags: android, webrtc

When I call video by webrtc in Android and receive all frame of video remote but some device video render not good. It delay render increase 1s->15s after it removes old frame and render real time.

How can I remove old frame which waiting for render > 5s?

Answer (score 1):

Latency can occur due to limited CPU computation power of a device or limited network bandwidth.

You may want to limit the video resolution or bitrate.

Check the `maxBitrate` parameter
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#rtcrtpencodingparameters

Comment: i set maxBitrate 1700, width: 640 height: 360. messenger call video very smooth. If  Latency  occur due to limited CPU computation power of a device so how to disable frame which waiting render( i think it will make user not see delay )